# Comparar id de duas tabelas e inserir valor quando id não existir

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou comparando duas tabelas que possuem os mesmos dados, `tabela1` e `tabela2`, a `tabela2` terá dados excluídos com o passar do tempo, e por isso preciso identificar o campo que foi excluído e inserir um "status de exclusão" em uma coluna da `tabela1`.

Tentarei explicar dessa forma:

```
+---------+---------+----------+
| TABELA2 | TABELA1 |          |
+---------+---------+----------+
| cod1    | cod1    |          |
+---------+---------+----------+
|         | cod2    | EXCLUIDO |
+---------+---------+----------+
| cod3    | cod3    |          |
+---------+---------+----------+
|         | cod4    | EXCLUIDO |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

Código que já tenho, ele já realiza a comparação mas não inclui o status de "excluído":

```
$teste1 = "SELECT * FROM tabela2 as a INNER JOIN tabela1 as c ON (a.cod2=c.cod1)";
    $teste2 = mysqli_query ($db,$teste1);
    while($teste3 = mysqli_fetch_array($teste2)){
        $teste = $teste3["0"];

        $insert = "UPDATE tabela1 SET campo = 'Entregue' WHERE cod1 NOT IN ($teste)";
        mysqli_query ($db,$insert);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá você pode executar a consulta abaixo para saber quem foi excluido:

```
select * from tabela1 t1  where not exists(select * from tabela2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id )
```

E para atualizar o status você pode executar apenas o comando abaixo:

```
update tabela1 t1 set t1.status = "EXCLUIDO" where not exists(select * from tabela2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id )
```

Veja os exemplos aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb5a21/3

Comment: Muitooo obrigado!! Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado mesmo!